# How to associate ID from pandas dataframe of longlat points with second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains the ID and coordinates of some points

```
df
    ID   x          y           geometry
0   0   -73.847701  18.024993   POINT (-73.84770051912155 18.02499306784136)
1   1   -73.849600  18.025617   POINT (-73.84959983488658 18.02561663390971)
2   2   -73.860621  18.031506   POINT (-73.86062088694281 18.03150628817371)
3   3   -73.864964  18.025705   POINT (-73.86496448074752 18.02570510646184)
4   4   -73.791759  18.031940   POINT (-73.79175934035219 18.03194019925698)
```

then I have a dataframe that contains the start and the end of a line

```
df1
    start                                       end
0   (-73.84770051912155 18.02499306784136)  (-73.84959983488658 18.02561663390971)
1   (-73.84959983488658 18.02561663390971)  (-73.86496448074752 18.02570510646184)
```

I would like to associate to `start` and `end` their `ID` in `df` instead of the coordinates.

Comment: it is always a good practice to show the desired output to facilitate correct answers. Show how you would like the end result to actually look like.

Answer (score 0):

I would first take the word POINT away:

```
df["geometry"] = df["geometry"].map(lambda x: x.str.split("POINT ")[1])

#Output
    ID   x          y           geometry
0   0   -73.847701  18.024993   (-73.84770051912155 18.02499306784136)
1   1   -73.849600  18.025617   (-73.84959983488658 18.02561663390971)
2   2   -73.860621  18.031506   (-73.86062088694281 18.03150628817371)
3   3   -73.864964  18.025705   (-73.86496448074752 18.02570510646184)
4   4   -73.791759  18.031940   (-73.79175934035219 18.03194019925698)
```

Then find out which ID is associated with start and stop for each row:

```
df1["start"] = df1["start"].map(lambda x: df.loc[df.geometry==x,"ID"].values[0])
df1["stop"] = df1["stop"].map(lambda x: df.loc[df.geometry==x,"ID"].values[0])
```

Here I assumed that the IDs point to unique locations.

```
#Output
    start   stop
0     0     1
1     1     3
```

I hope I understood your question correctly. Otherwise you can post an example of how the output should look like.

Comment: small typo: df["geometry"] =  should be df["geometry_clean"] =